# Text-center wont work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem that I have with my code is that the `<p>Welcome to my Profile</p>` will not center. I've tried using Bootstrap's `text-center` class but it doesn't work desirably. I've also tried multiple things like using `text-align: center;` in CSS and even using `width: 100%;` for both the header and the div. Are there any solutions? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Jane's Personal Profile</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Jane Doe</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offset2 text-center">
            <p>Welcome to my Profile</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  height: 75px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px grey;
  width: 100%;
}

header > h1 {
 float: left; 
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Could you please include a fiddle or live example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Appears to be working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ouroborus/xwp4fp3g/

Comment: You appear to be using Bootstrap. If so, add that tag to your question. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @AndrewL. New to this, don't know what you mean sorry :(.

Comment: @Ouroborus this is what I see http://imgur.com/a/CXlVX

Comment: @j08691 no errors: http://imgur.com/a/9Ue8x

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using, in v2.1.1 - 2.2.2 text-center is not a bootstrap class it appears in v2.3 so im guessing your using the wrong bootstrap.css file. http://www.bootply.com/irbd6opPBS

Comment: @Bosc Hmm; I tried the latest Bootstrap and tried the given code; reproduces the problem

Comment: @Bosc even adding `text-align: center;` to my CSS, does not work, which is essentially all that .text-center does in bootstrap.

Comment: @FireKiN I can collaborate over JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b2nh1s8g/#&togetherjs=eyn0wbH9Bs)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using "text-center" as a class. Unless you set your CSS to recognize the class, there is nothing for the CSS to do.

Try adding this to your CSS

```
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You should always provide a jsFiddle for problems like this, btw ;)

If Bootstrap has a class setting the paragraph element to align left, you may also need to change the paragraph to a div. Alternatively, you could add a class to the paragraph such as "center-me" and add CSS

```
p.center-me {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Bootstrap adds a giant bunch of CSS. Make sure, when you are using Bootstrap, to check if it has CSS styles that are affecting what you want to accomplish. Most browsers contain a developer's window where you can see what styles are being applied to any window. In Chrome, you can right click on any element and select "Inspect" to pull up this window and see both the HTML and the styles that are being applied from any CSS source.

Comment: `text-center` is a class from Bootstrap. It applies `text-align: center;`

Comment: you did not mention bootstrap in your question. Also, if you mark people down because their answers did not work for you, though you did not provide complete information or a jsFiddle to test on, you will not get good answers for long.

Comment: I'm not the original poster; and the code uses a link to Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: @AndrewL a bit less aggression please, you have made me consider if I should still be contributing at all. If your goal is to drive away potential contributors, carry on.

Comment: @jedifans sorry for that; I'll keep myself in check

Comment: Hah, thanks @Deborah! @Andrew thanks and no worries.  I responded based on information in the question and didn't see the bootstrap related classes, having never used it myself.

Comment: Both did not work. Just for reference, this is what I see: http://imgur.com/a/CXlVX

Comment: @FireKin, please make a JSfiddle that includes Bootstrap. There is something interfering with your CSS, but it is not possible to tell what without seeing more of the code that is affecting it.

Comment: @Deborah Got it fixed, thanks to @AndrewL and another unknown user. He figured out that the `class=span8 offset2 text-center` was for an older version of bootstrap. Using the newer version he used `class=col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center` which centered the text. Thanks for your help though,